# convert JSON data into table based on elements seperated by \n for header elements and \t for table elements using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
"results": {
                    "code": "SUCCESS",
                    "msg": [
                        {
                            "type": "TABLE",
                            "data": "id\tfirstname\tlastname\n1\tJack\tSmith\n2\tAdam\tJohnson\n3\tKim\tSmith\n4\tDavid\tWilliams\n5\tPeter\tDavis\n6\tJack\tSmith\n7\tAdam\tJohnson\n8\tKim\tSmith\n9\tDavid\tWilliams\n10\tPeter\tDavis\n11\tPeter\n31\tJack\tSmith\n32\tAdam\tJohnson\n33\tKim\tSmith\n34\tDavid\tWilliams\n35\tPeter\tDavis\n"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

this is my example code,where ever we have \n consider as header elements of table and \t  consider as tr elements,can you provide me any suggestion.

Comment: is there any specific reason for using this type of data / JSON?

Comment: Not only is this an odd choice for how to send your data from your server,  you don't even appear to understand how the data string really is structured.  It looks more like you have `\t` between each data value and `\n` at the end of each line of data (which makes sense, since `\t` is the tab character and `\n` is the newline character).  The headers appear to be the first row.  There isn't really anything AngularJs can do to help you separate the data;  Perhaps a JavaScript function to loop through the string might be what you want.

Comment: do a bit of research on how to split a tab delimited dataset.

Comment: agreed with @claies, looping through the data will also degrade the performance. which will also increase an object and variable size if you use to manipulate. it's better you handle from server side by sending a header in one object and data in other.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,can you help to convert this data into table format?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking something like this. In your HTML code right one ng repeat for head and other for each row of the table.

```js
var result = {
    "code": "SUCCESS",
    "msg": [{
        "type": "TABLE",
        "data": "id\tfirstname\tlastname\n1\tJack\tSmith\n2\tAdam\tJohnson\n3\tKim\tSmith\n4\tDavid\tWilliams\n5\tPeter\tDavis\n6\tJack\tSmith\n7\tAdam\tJohnson\n8\tKim\tSmith\n9\tDavid\tWilliams\n10\tPeter\tDavis\n11\tPeter\n31\tJack\tSmith\n32\tAdam\tJohnson\n33\tKim\tSmith\n34\tDavid\tWilliams\n35\tPeter\tDavis\n"
    }]
}

var format = result.msg.map((r) => {
    var str = r.data;
    var arr = str.split('\n');
    var head = arr.splice(0, 1)[0].split('\t');
    arr.pop(); // remove empty string
    var data = arr.map((d) => {
        return d.split('\t').reduce((obj, x, index) => {
            obj[head[index]] = x;
            return obj;
        }, {})
    })
    return {
        head,
        data
    }
});

console.log(format);
```

Comment: thanks,how can we convert this JSON data into table,based on \n and \t